# Why In StringBuilder we cannot Replace the Entire Contents with the Processed Contents of the StringBuilder?

Tags: c#

When we Process a String Builder Contents, Why cannot we replace the existing contents with the Processed Value.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("Hello");
sb.Append(SomeProcessText(sb.ToString()));
MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());

private string SomeProcessText(string text)
 {
      // Some Processing of 'text' value.
      text = "Chello"
      return text;
 }
```

The Code above will give a value "HelloChello"

Whereas I expect that the Processed Value should replace the existing value in StringBuilder and give "Chello"

I think Microsoft should have a Simple method called ClearAppend() so that we can simply say

```
sb.ClearAppend(SomeProcessText(sb.ToString()));

or 

sb.ReplaceAll(SomeProcessText(sb.ToString()));
```

which will Replace the Contents of the StringBuilder with the Processed Value.

If we have to do this what I have done below, then what is the point of having a StringBuilder if we have to use a String Variable to hold the value temporarily, which allocates a new Location in Memory Stack.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("Hello");
string temp = SomeProcessText(sb.ToString());
sb.Clear();
sb.Append(temp);
```

But till Microsoft can think about it, what could be the way out here.

Comment: Why not convert the `StringBuilder` to string then do the processing on that? Or do the processing on the text before adding the the `StringBuilder`?

Comment: This is just an example. If i use a string variable then why not use string variables. Then what is the use of a StringBuilder if it does not have lots of functions in it to manipulate the text value in it. String variable manipulated keeps adding to memory stack.

Comment: *"I expect that the Processed Value should replace the existing value"* - Why?  You're calling a method on the `StringBuilder` called `Append`.  As advertised, that method *appends* the text.  Perhaps you meant to call the `Clear()` method on it first?

Comment: I think you misunderstand the purpose of StringBuilder. StringBuilder is useful for avoiding excessive string allocations when concatenating strings.

Comment: So why is there NO ReplaceAll() method

Comment: You could do `sb.Replace(sb.ToString(), SomeProcessText(sb.ToString()));`

Comment: Are you asking about a specific problem in your code?  Or are you asking why Microsoft hasn't made methods that you want them to make?  We're not the creators of the .NET Framework, so we can't answer the latter.  You could always make your own methods (even extension methods) to perform the logic you want to perform.

Comment: If i have a string Private field in a class and i keep altering its value in the methods in the class, then every change i make to that variable allocates new memory location space. Eats up memory.

Comment: Thanks @juharr that is what i wanted. It works.

Comment: @BeeGees If you're worried about memory you're better off with the temp variable, clear, and then append.

Comment: @juharr why is that so. I feel your method will replace the contents and not eat up memory.

Comment: @BeeGees Both `ToString` calls will allocate new `string` objects, also `Replace` is less efficient than `Clear` as it has to iterate the characters to find the match.

Comment: @juharr Ok nice explanation. As i mentioned in my question, they should have had a Method like ClearAppend(). Also I want to ask you, is it safe to have Temporary Method level string variables. Is the memory occupied by such a temp string variable released once the method execution is completed,even though other methods are still being executed.

Comment: local reference variables are available for garbage collection as soon as they go out of scope.

Comment: Thanks @juharr you have been great help.

Comment: @juharr: Variables aren't garbage collected: objects are. Whether the object that a local variable value refers to is eligible for garbage collection when the local variable goes out of scope depends on whether anything else has a reference to the same object.

Answer (score 3):

Why would it "replace" the contents of the value? You [`appended`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.append?view=netcore-3.1) the result of your method to the `StringBuilder`

In other words, it's doing *exactly* what your code does.

1. You `appended` "Hello"
2. You `appended` the result of your method which returns "Chello"

Result "HelloChello" in your `MessageBox`

---

> *they should have had a Method like ClearAppend()*

Microsoft doesn't but as @David mentioned, you can create your own [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) that [`StringBuilder.Clear`s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.clear?view=netcore-3.1) and subsequently `Append()`s for whatever your use case is.